# What is the Mandarin equivalent of 唔夾 in Cantonese (i.e., not complementary)?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

In Cantonese, you can say 唔夾 to say A and B are not complementary. What's the equivalent in Mandarin?

不合 or 不搭?

Comment: cf. bkrs:般配 match; suit; be well matched; match each other syn.班配 方言。谓彼此条件相当，配得上。同义: 匹配, 配合, 相配, 比配

Comment: @user6065 thanks, why not post as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'People being incompatible' is 唔夾 or 合唔來 in Cantonese and  合不來 or 不合 in Mandarin

> These two people have always been **incompatible** with each other
>
> 佢哋兩個一向**唔夾** (Cantonese)
>
> 他們二人一向**合不來** (Mandarin)
>
> 他們二人向來**不合** (Mandarin)

'Things being incompatible' in Cantonese can also be 唔夾, and 不般配 in Mandarin.

> Chinese medicine and Western medicine are incompatible
>
> 中藥同西藥**唔夾** (Cantonese)
>
> 中藥跟西藥**不般配** (Mandarin)

Comment: thanks for contrasting cantonese and mandarin! makes things much easier! :)

Comment: how about 不搭? also does this sentence contain an extra 來: 他們二人向來不合?

Comment: (1.)不搭 can replace 不般配 in Mandarin when describe things being  incompatible. For example,  '中藥跟西藥不搭' ( 2,) 唔搭 can replace 唔夾 in Cantonese when describe things being incompatible.  For example,  '中藥同西藥唔搭'  (3) For people being incompatible,  唔夾 in Cantonese; and 合不來/不合 in Mandarin are the correct terms. We don't say '佢地兩個一向唔搭' in Cantonese; or '他們二人一向不搭' in Mandarin (4.) Both  '向來' and '一向'  mean 'always' .  They are interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

不合适，不般配， off the top of my head.

Comment: 不合适 means 'unsuitable' , for example,  合适的人選 (suitable candidates);  不合适的人選 (unsuitable candidates)

Comment: 不般配 means 'improper'. It is more often used to describe 'things being incompatible', for example, 高跟鞋和短褲不般配 (high heels and shorts are not fit together)